# Input output in Wolfram Cloud

Tags: expression-manipulation

This is a starter query. I know if I enter `2+2` and press enter, I get `4`.

Similarly, I enter `expr = 5x + x^3 + Sin[x]` and press enter. Next, I want to perform an operation with it, which is to extract the power of `x`, i.e., 3. This is not clear to me, how to single out this operation on Wolfram Cloud to do so. All I see is a new line after `expr = 5x + x^3 + Sin[x]` and enter.

[image]

Comment: Try `expr[[2]]` instead

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and it depends a lot on your use case which is more valid/logical in which context (as in, the context of your use case, not that of the `Context` you are currently working in!). I notice immediately that your syntax needs to be improved, namely, it should be `Sin[x]` not `sin[x]`. I highly suggest you go through the elementary introduction to the wolfram language, which is available for free online, or one of the other introductory works that are also available for free online in an interactive fashion.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2349128).